# Can Direct3D 11 do offscreen-only rendering (no swap chain)?

Tags: directx, render-to-texture, direct3d11

Is it possible to use Direct3D 11 for rendering to textures only, i.e. without creating a swap chain and without creating any window? I have tried that and all my API calls succeed. The only problem is that the picture I am downloading from a staging texture is black.

I finally managed to capture a full stream using PIX (Parallel Nsight does not seem to work at all). PIX shows that my render target is black, too, although I clear it to blue.

Is it possible at all what I intend to do? If so, how would one do it?

Comment: Not very clear of your question, what's your purpose? why not paste some code or explain why do you want to do this?

Comment: I just want to render to an Image and display nothing.

Comment: if you don't present the scene, how do you know it rendered correctly? do you want to render only one frame or several frames?

Comment: I copy it to a staging texture and map that one. Then I save the mapped image to disk. It all works perfectly if you select the right adapter and correctly create the D3D device from it.

Comment: @Chhristoph only one frame?

Comment: No, of course not. But I can repeate the render-to-texture and download steps any time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the whole thing is working as intended if you initialise the device correctly.